# replace files names with names from separate file

Tags: unix

I have files in a directory that I want to renames with the names in the file `names.txt`. The names in `names.txt` are ordered similar to those in the directory I want to change. Can this be done i unix?

Answer (score 0):

One script like this ca do the work:

```
for i in `ls`
do
a=$(grep $i names.txt|awk '{print $2})
mv "$i" "$a"
done
```

suppose in names.txt you have format

```
source_name target_name
```

This script will be not so much reliable if you have names which contain space or other special characters .